# VSCode Copy Relative Path with posix forward slashes

Tags: visual-studio-code, relative-path

VSC newbie here.

I'm trying to right-click on my projects' files and selecting `Copy Relative Path`, the thing is I get the path like this:
`node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css`

when what I actually need is this:
`node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Where can I change these settings to avoid the manual editing, It's really time consuming.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 63):

As of vscode 1.59 you can enable using the `/` separator even on Windows for the `Copy Relative Path` command.

`Explorer: Copy Relative Path Separator` set to `/`.

`explorer.copyRelativePathSeparator`

- `auto` (default): Uses operating system specific path separation character
- `/`: Use slash as path separation character
- `\\`: Use backslash as path separation character

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56279

[image]

---

For the same ability to designate the path separator for the copy full path (tab context menu: `Copy Path`) command, there is an issue with a PR awaiting resolution: [Allow to configure the which slash is used when copying a path](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164153).

Comment: Perfect, this made my day.  Absolutely essential if you are using the (Git) Bash terminal on Windows VSCode.  For instance if you want to do a `git diff main -- my/foo/bar/relative/path` whereas the default (auto) behavior will barf on `git diff main -- my\foo\bar\relative\path`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you used Windows, which uses `\` instead of `/` in paths. I suggest using raw strings in the path. For example: `r'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'`.

Another way to change all the `\` to `/` is by using the replace function in vscode!